# Out of memory error on getDrawable()

Tags: android, bitmap, wallpaper

I want to get the current image set as the wallpaper in Android device and set it to the image view in my list after scaling it . What i am doing id this:

```
final WallpaperManager wm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
final Drawable wallpaperDrawable = wm.getDrawable();
Bitmap bitmap = drawableToBitmap(wallpaperDrawable);
imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

The drawableToBitmap Function is as follows:

```
public static Bitmap drawableToBitmap (Drawable drawable) {
    if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
        return ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();
    }

    int width = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
    width = width > 0 ? width : 1;
    int height = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
    height = height > 0 ? height : 1;

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    drawable.draw(canvas);

    return bitmap;
}
```

But i get this error :

```
01-29 13:30:50.150: E/dalvikvm-heap(3281): Out of memory on a 3891216-byte allocation.
    01-29 13:30:50.160: I/dalvikvm(3281): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
    01-29 13:30:50.160: I/dalvikvm(3281):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x409c0460 self=0x12810
    01-29 13:30:50.170: I/dalvikvm(3281):   | sysTid=3281 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1074082952
    01-29 13:30:50.180: I/dalvikvm(3281):   | schedstat=( 1725234737 955825527 142 ) utm=152 stm=20 core=0
    01-29 13:30:50.190: I/dalvikvm(3281):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
    01-29 13:30:50.190: I/dalvikvm(3281):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:605)
    01-29 13:30:50.190: I/dalvikvm(3281):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:585)
    01-29 13:30:50.190: I/dalvikvm(3281):   at android.app.WallpaperManager.generateBitmap(WallpaperManager.java:729)
    01-29 13:30:50.190: I/dalvikvm(3281):   at android.app.WallpaperManager$Globals.getCurrentWallpaperLocked(WallpaperManager.java:265)
    01-29 13:30:50.200: I/dalvikvm(3281):   at android.app.WallpaperManager$Globals.peekWallpaperBitmap(WallpaperManager.java:230)
    01-29 13:30:50.200: I/dalvikvm(3281):   at android.app.WallpaperManager.getDrawable(WallpaperManager.java:350)
    01-29 13:30:50.210: I/dalvikvm(3281):   at storeapps.com.profilechanger.ListActivity.onCreate(ListActivity.java:64)
    01-29 13:30:50.210: I/dalvikvm(3281):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4466)
    01-29 13:30:50.220: I/dalvikvm(3281):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
    01-29 13:30:50.220: I/dalvikvm(3281):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
    01-29 13:30:50.220: I/dalvikvm(3281):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
    01-29 13:30:50.220: I/dalvikvm(3281):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
    01-29 13:30:50.220: I/dalvikvm(3281):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
    01-29 13:30:50.220: I/dalvikvm(3281):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    01-29 13:30:50.220: I/dalvikvm(3281):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    01-29 13:30:50.230: I/dalvikvm(3281):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
    01-29 13:30:50.230: I/dalvikvm(3281):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    01-29 13:30:50.230: I/dalvikvm(3281):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    01-29 13:30:50.230: I/dalvikvm(3281):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
    01-29 13:30:50.230: I/dalvikvm(3281):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
    01-29 13:30:50.230: I/dalvikvm(3281):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    01-29 13:30:50.270: I/Process(570): Sending signal. PID: 3281 SIG: 3
    01-29 13:30:50.270: I/dalvikvm(3281): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
    01-29 13:30:50.310: W/WallpaperManager(3281): Can't generate default bitmap
    01-29 13:30:50.310: W/WallpaperManager(3281): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    01-29 13:30:50.310: W/WallpaperManager(3281):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
    01-29 13:30:50.310: W/WallpaperManager(3281):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:605)
    01-29 13:30:50.310: W/WallpaperManager(3281):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:585)
    01-29 13:30:50.310: W/WallpaperManager(3281):   at android.app.WallpaperManager.generateBitmap(WallpaperManager.java:729)
    01-29 13:30:50.310: W/WallpaperManager(3281):   at android.app.WallpaperManager$Globals.getCurrentWallpaperLocked(WallpaperManager.java:265)
    01-29 13:30:50.310: W/WallpaperManager(3281):   at android.app.WallpaperManager$Globals.peekWallpaperBitmap(WallpaperManager.java:230)
    01-29 13:30:50.310: W/WallpaperManager(3281):   at android.app.WallpaperManager.getDrawable(WallpaperManager.java:350)
    01-29 13:30:50.310: W/WallpaperManager(3281):   at storeapps.com.profilechanger.ListActivity.onCreate(ListActivity.java:64)
    01-29 13:30:50.310: W/WallpaperManager(3281):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4466)
    01-29 13:30:50.310: W/WallpaperManager(3281):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
    01-29 13:30:50.310: W/WallpaperManager(3281):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
    01-29 13:30:50.310: W/WallpaperManager(3281):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
    01-29 13:30:50.310: W/WallpaperManager(3281):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
    01-29 13:30:50.310: W/WallpaperManager(3281):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
    01-29 13:30:50.310: W/WallpaperManager(3281):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    01-29 13:30:50.310: W/WallpaperManager(3281):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    01-29 13:30:50.310: W/WallpaperManager(3281):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
    01-29 13:30:50.310: W/WallpaperManager(3281):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    01-29 13:30:50.310: W/WallpaperManager(3281):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    01-29 13:30:50.310: W/WallpaperManager(3281):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
    01-29 13:30:50.310: W/WallpaperManager(3281):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
    01-29 13:30:50.310: W/WallpaperManager(3281):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    01-29 13:30:50.310: D/ProfileChangerApp(3281):  wallpaper manager is :android.app.WallpaperManager@41085b88
    01-29 13:30:50.320: D/ProfileChangerApp(3281): image is not null
    01-29 13:30:50.320: I/dalvikvm(3281): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
    01-29 13:30:50.340: D/AndroidRuntime(3281): Shutting down VM
    01-29 13:30:50.371: W/dalvikvm(3281): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409bf1f8)
    01-29 13:30:50.430: E/AndroidRuntime(3281): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    01-29 13:30:50.430: E/AndroidRuntime(3281): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{storeapps.com.profilechanger/storeapps.com.profilechanger.ListActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    01-29 13:30:50.430: E/AndroidRuntime(3281):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
    01-29 13:30:50.430: E/AndroidRuntime(3281):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
    01-29 13:30:50.430: E/AndroidRuntime(3281):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
    01-29 13:30:50.430: E/AndroidRuntime(3281):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
    01-29 13:30:50.430: E/AndroidRuntime(3281):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    01-29 13:30:50.430: E/AndroidRuntime(3281):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    01-29 13:30:50.430: E/AndroidRuntime(3281):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
    01-29 13:30:50.430: E/AndroidRuntime(3281):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    01-29 13:30:50.430: E/AndroidRuntime(3281):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    01-29 13:30:50.430: E/AndroidRuntime(3281):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
    01-29 13:30:50.430: E/AndroidRuntime(3281):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
    01-29 13:30:50.430: E/AndroidRuntime(3281):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    01-29 13:30:50.430: E/AndroidRuntime(3281): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    01-29 13:30:50.430: E/AndroidRuntime(3281):     at storeapps.com.profilechanger.ListActivity.onCreate(ListActivity.java:70)
    01-29 13:30:50.430: E/AndroidRuntime(3281):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4466)
    01-29 13:30:50.430: E/AndroidRuntime(3281):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
    01-29 13:30:50.430: E/AndroidRuntime(3281):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
    01-29 13:30:50.430: E/AndroidRuntime(3281):     ... 11 more
```

Please help me !

Comment: Hi friend,Please compress image before set to ImageView

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34327699/byte-and-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-read-write-file-by-bits/34327864#34327864

Comment: @PankajNimgade i tried this but yet not working ,

Comment: @beginner, what you need to do here is resize the bitmap image, you will get this error if the image is too big. here is a question, you can see the person who asked the question is scaling the image down http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34661257/load-applications-icons-and-getting-outofmemory-exception-while-resizing/34661894#34661894

Comment: @beginner, what is the size of image you are trying to render ?

Comment: is there any problem using `RGB_565` ?

Comment: @PankajNimgade i am trying to show the image taken out from the current wallpaper in my list , image view size is 80*80 and i have text view also with it.. the image size is 1280*1440

Comment: Thanks all. But i solved it from solution from somewhere that when used on emulator this happens but hen used on original device. this doesnt happen. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resize your image **Bitmap**

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.yourImageName);
```

Above line will get `Bitmap` from `Drawable`. No need to do anything apart from adding the above line to get a `Bitmap` from a `Drawable`.

```
int height = (bitmap.getHeight() * 512 / bitmap.getWidth());
Bitmap scale = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 512, height, true);
imageView.setImageBitmap(scale);
```

Comment: I tried this, but still getting the same error   :                                             final WallpaperManager wm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
        final Drawable wallpaperDrawable = wm.getDrawable(); Bitmap bitmap = drawableToBitmap(wallpaperDrawable);
        int height = (bitmap.getHeight() * 512 / bitmap.getWidth());
        Bitmap scale = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 512,height, true);
        imageview.setImageBitmap(scale);

Comment: decodeResource requires the id if the drawable image but i have the drawable image taken out from the getDrawable

Comment: It works but costs a lot of cpu power and causes shutters

Answer (score 3):

Don't put drawables that are not vector drawables into `DRAWABLE` but into `DRAWABLE-NODPI` instead. Otherwise on some devices you are going to get OOME because they were scaled and had higher memory usage. Happens on Samsungs more

Answer (score 2):

### Whats your Logcat Throws

> 01-29 13:30:50.310: W/WallpaperManager(3281):
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Thrown when a request for memory is made that can not be satisfied using the available platform resources. Such a request may be made by both the running application or by an internal function of the **VM or Device** .

1. **Compress image before set to ImageView**

> Creates a new bitmap, scaled from an existing bitmap, when possible.
>   If the specified width and height are the same as the current width
>   and height of the source bitmap, the source bitmap is returned and no
>   new bitmap is created.

```
Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(YourImageBitMap, 100, 50, true);
```

2. **Reduces your images size** .

You can read **[How to deal with the OutOfMemoryError](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/exceptions/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-how-to-solve-outofmemoryerror/)** &

**[Strange out of memory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object)**

Answer (score 1):

```
Drawable wallpaper = getApplicationContext().getWallpaper();
```

The `wallpaper` is a reference.

`Bitmap.createBitmap` might make OOM exception.

`WindowManager` source code:

```
// This is the final bitmap we want to return.
try {
Bitmap newbm = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

Answer (score 0):

android:largeHeap="true" in your manifest application tag